# Android - Integrate iJetty Server In my Own Application

Tags: android, jetty, httplistener, ijetty

Can anyone tell me or guide me how to integrate iJetty webserver in my own application, I want to implement its HttpListener feature in my application so that I can send and receive data over the local network using WIFI.

I want to be able to implement HTTP verbs like "POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE" through iJetty

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this on my own if anyone else wants to know follow the link.

http://codersapprentice.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-integrate-jetty-server-in-my.html

Comment: @KhabZeeshan can you update the required libraries image in that blog ? or can you suggest which libraries are required ?